# Eclipse Kepler JavaEE version - How to add dependent project classes

Tags: dependencies, war, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to find a way to build my web application project to contain dependent projects java classes merged into WEB-INF/classes directory rather creating dependent project jar files and keeping under WEB-INF/lib directory. I have been playing with 'Properties' -> 'Deployment Assembly' but no luck! Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why to create dependant java projects just to add the classes, and not the JAR itself ? Why not to create those classes directly on the webapp ? (Unless you want to use only a few Utils from a full Utils JAR, as example)

Comment: I have already some pre-existing projects and my requirement is to have dependent project java class files into WEB-INF/classes folder. Having jars wouldn't do as there are some web resources which will miss out.

Comment: I think an ANT script would do this task perfectly for you

Comment: I know there are many better ways of doing. I can use ANT/Maven or any other build tool. But, the project I'm working can't afford those given the timescales because of legacy issues.